# How to append text in end of row, without reading the text file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a text file whose data could look like this.

```
data0 ; data1 
10000 ; 88282
55002 ; 75555
10002 ; 22550
22222 ; 58799
....
78954 ; 54647
```

Then I want to add data to it, which will make the file look like below.
The data that was in the file should never change.

```
data0 ; data1 ; data2
10000 ; 88282 ; 51485
55002 ; 75555 ; 48526
10002 ; 22550 ; 47892
22222 ; 58799 ; 36258
....
78954 ; 54647 ; 58429
```

I want to add data to every line.
I know you could do this by reading the entire file. Then add the data to this and then write it back to the file. But the problem is that I will have a lot of data.
If I have to read out and write back all this data every time, this takes too much time.

**Hence I wondered if there is no method to add data on a particular line without having to read out all data first.**

Comment: It's one file, not random access. So you will have reasonable speed on any recent hardware (40€ ssd from 2014 is around 3-6gb/s). You can cut the read/write in half by not reading and simply creating a new file.   Or pushing the data into a database. But File stream do allow random access. So in theory you can save the position of all endline, and write there. But you will have to make sure that you are at the right byte offset, start of a character in the right encoding.

Comment: Are there methods in C # that you can write to a specific byte in a file? @DragandDrop

Comment: With [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-5.0), you can change the [position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.position?view=net-5.0). But I will not do it that way. I know that loading everything in memory look slow. So why don't you just open 2 stream one for reading, one for writing. read one line modify and write it in the second stream.

Comment: If I open 1 stream to read and 1 to write, I still have to write the entire line back. But with file stream you can only write bytes, right? @DragandDrop

Comment: @Lauradebaets: Since you are changing the length of the line, you have to rewrite the entire portion of the file after that line (shifting it over to make room for the line to grow).

Comment: _"...without having to read out all data first."_ -- not possible. See duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put simply, no. The issue is just because of the direction you are storing your data. Without reading every break line or return carriage you will not be able to append a new column in your data structure. Since you mentioned "The data that was in the file should never change." Then why not invert your table?

Eg:
Instead of storing it like this;

```
data0 ; data1 
10000 ; 88282
55002 ; 75555
10002 ; 22550
22222 ; 58799
....
78954 ; 54647
```

Do this;

```
data0:10000,55002,10002,22222,....,78954
data1:88282,75555,22550,58799,....,54674
```

This way, now all you have to do is append new data to your file like

C#:

```
File.AppendAllText("table.txt", Environment.NewLine + newtableData);
```

or bash:

```
echo '\n\rnewtableData' >> filename
```